# How can I get the value / keys of NSDictionary objects in the debugger console?

Tags: objective-c, ios, lldb

I set a breakpoint...

if I do:

```
(lldb) print [self dictionary]
(NSDictionary *) $5 = 0x0945c760 1 key/value pair
```

but if I do:

```
(lldb) print [[self dictionary] allKeys]
error: no known method '-allKeys'; cast the message send to the method's return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

Even if I try to access the key that I know is in there..

```
(lldb) print [[self dictionary] objectForKey:@"foobar"]
error: no known method '-objectForKey:'; cast the message send to the method's return     type
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
error: no known method '-objectForKey:'; cast the message send to the method's return type
```

So, it tells you it can't deduce return type information merely from the name of the message send - and that's perfectly fine. And it even tells you how exactly you have to resolve that problem - you have to *cast* the message send to *the method's return type*.

Firing up Apple's docs, we find out that `- [NSDictionary objectForKey:]` returns `id` - the generic Objective-C object type. Casting to id (or even better, if you know what types of objects your dictionary holds, casting to that exact object type) does the trick:

```
(lldb) print (MyObject *)[(NSDictionary *)[self dictionary] objectForKey:@"foobar"]
```

Comment: I thank your smart aleck self! :) I will leave another example of this problem:
**Fail:** `print [[[self.collectionView gestureRecognizers] objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]`
**Good:** `print (BOOL)[[[self.collectionView gestureRecognizers] objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:(Class)[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]` Note the 2 casts required to make it work.

Comment: Leave it to Objective C to take the simple out of stupidly simple.

Answer (score 15):

The lldb command print expects that the value you wish to print is a non-object.  The command you should be using to print objects is po.

When you tell lldb to print the value it looks for a method called allKeys that returns a non-object and fails.  Try the following command instead...

```
po [[self dictionary] allKeys]
```

Answer (score 3):

To print the `description` of the object in GDB or LLDB you need to use [`print-object`](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/General/Debugging.html) or `po`.

```
(lldb) po [self dictionary]
(lldb) po [[self dictionary] objectForKey:@"foobar"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do

```
NSLog(@"dict: %@", dictionary);
```

or

```
NSLog(@"dict objectForKey:foobar = %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"foobar"]);
```

Comment: I think he's trying to get the information from the console not source code. However it is the better way to do it in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in lldb at the moment causing `po dictionary[@"key"]` to print an empty line rather than the key's value. Use `[dictionary[@"key"] description]` to get the value instead.